# mysql query works with some particular records only not with all of the data

Tags: mysql

[image: student_detail table]

[image: payment_detail with all data]
[image: payment_detail table![]

first image of student_detail table,second is image of payment_detail table when i fire the query like

```
SELECT `student_detail`.`id`,
  `student_detail`.`first_name`,
  `student_detail`.`last_name`,
  `student_detail`.`course`,
  `payment_detail`.`id`,
  `student_id`,
  `inst_paid_date`,
  `next_inst_date`,
  `paid_installment`,
  `next_installment_amount` 
 FROM `student_detail`,`payment_detail` 
WHERE MONTH(`next_inst_date`)=MONTH(now()) 
  AND `inst_paid_date`<`next_inst_date` 
  AND `student_detail`.`id`=`student_id` 
  AND `student_id`='10' 
  AND `inst_paid_date` in(select max(`inst_paid_date`) from `payment_detail`)
```

it do not give any result when records are present like second table but if i delete student id 8 and 9 it gives the result other wise not i cant get how it is conflict with other records when perticularly set the where condition with student_id=10. thanks in advanced

Comment: Please create a fiddle in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the data and update the question with the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you limit your `inst_paid_date` to the maximum value across the entire `payment_detail` table. Since this maximum value is for student id 9 when it is present, this conflicts with your filter on student id 10.

Try to add the same filter to your subquery like this:

```
 WHERE 
     ...     
     AND `student_id`='10' 
     AND `inst_paid_date` in (select max(`inst_paid_date`) 
                              from `payment_detail`
                              where `student_id` = '10')
```

A more generic solution would be to turn the subquery into a correlated subquery. This requires an alias on the outer reference to the `payment_detail` table:

```
...
FROM `student_detail`,`payment_detail` as `PD`
WHERE MONTH(`next_inst_date`)=MONTH(now()) 
  AND `inst_paid_date`<`next_inst_date` 
  AND `student_detail`.`id`=`student_id` 
  AND `PD`.`student_id`='10' 
  AND `inst_paid_date` in(select max(`inst_paid_date`) 
                          from `payment_detail`
                          where `student_id` = `PD`.`student_id`)
```